# enabling/disabling asp.net web service extension via script

Tags: asp.net, iis

In IIS 6, I can use the Web Service Extensions folder in Inetmgr to allow/prohibit isapi filters, such as ASP.net. I want to be able to do this programmatically (in particular, from an installer script/exe).

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adding Web Service Extension Files Using Iisext.vbs](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b686f5cf-f84f-44be-af43-33916de846a3.mspx?mfr=true) should be pretty much what you're looking for (the linked article describes how to add a new filter: if you just need to enable it, scroll down and see the list of linked articles for exact instructions on how to achieve that)

Comment: Yes, it should: I don't have an XP box handy to check, but as long as the IIS WMI provider is available, iisext.vbs should work

Answer (score 2):

```
   Set iisinfo = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/Info")
   If CInt(iisinfo.MajorIIsVersionNumber) >= 6 Then
      Set iisinfo = Nothing
      Set iis = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC")
      iis.EnableWebServiceExtension "ASP"
   End If
```